# If $G,H$ are finite groups, then $G\times G\cong H \times H$ implies $G \cong H$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism, direct-product

> **Proposition**. Let $G,H$ be finite groups (abelian or not). Then the following implication holds: $$G\times G\cong H\times H \Rightarrow G\cong H.$$

In the case of $G,H$ both abelian, one can use the structure theorem (by looking at the invariant factors). Otherwise, I found an argument [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150793/if-g-times-g-cong-h-times-h-then-is-g-cong-h?noredirect=1&lq=1), which is a bit unclear to me. I will rephrase it in this post:

> **Lemma**. For a finite group $G$, the map ${\rm FinGr}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}, A\rightarrow |\text{Hom}(A, G)|$ (i.e. $A$ goes to the number of group homomorphisms from $A$ to $G$) uniquely determines $G$, up to isomorphism. Or equivalently, if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are two finite groups, such that for any finite group $A$ we have: $|\text{Hom}(A, G_1)|=|\text{Hom}(A, G_2)|$, then $G_1\cong G_2$.

**Proof proposition**: From $G\times G\cong H\times H$ we get $|\text{Hom}(A, G\times G)|=|\text{Hom}(A, H\times H)|$, for any finite group $A$. From the universal property of the direct product, we have: $|\text{Hom}(L, K\times K)|=|\text{Hom}(L, K)|^2$, for any groups $L,K$. We conclude that: $|\text{Hom}(A, G)|=|\text{Hom}(A, H)|$ for any finite group $A$. Using the previous lemma, we get the desired conclusion.

---

My question is: how do we prove this lemma? I tried some particular cases of $A$, cyclic, simple, but it doesn't bring much into light. (**EDIT**: My fault, I overlooked an answer to the lemma [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614496/if-lvert-operatornamehomh-g-1-rvert-lvert-operatornamehomh-g-2-rver?rq=1), which is not trivial and I still have hard time understanding it).

Anyway, if you have a more ellegant/elementary approach to the original proposition, you are more than welcome to share it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: That is *not* a trivial Lemma. Even showing that the family $\mathrm{Hom}(A,G)$ as $A$ ranges over all (isomorphism types) of groups completely determines $G$ is less than easy to do. There are easier ways of proving this result, for example, using the [Krull-Schmidt Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%E2%80%93Schmidt_theorem). )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Hom}{\text{Hom}}\newcommand{\Surj}{\text{Surj}}$I disagree with Arturo's comment: Proving this lemma is much easier than proving the Krull-Schmidt theorem! Most of the work is already in the linked question but, since you have trouble understanding the answers to the linked question, and since they are to a slightly different question ($|\Hom(H, G_1)| = |\Hom(H, G_2)|$ instead of $|\Hom(G_1, H)| = |\Hom(G_2, H)|$), I'll say some more.

For any two groups $G$ and $H$, let $\Surj(G,H)$ be the set of surjective group homomorphisms $G \to H$.

Now, suppose that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are finite groups such that $|\Hom(G_1, H)| = |\Hom(G_2, H)|$ for all $H$. I claim that we also have $|\Surj(G_1, H)| = |\Surj(G_2, H)|$.

**Proof of claim:** By induction on $|H|$; the base case of the trivial group is obvious. Since every homomorphism $G_i \to H$ has as image some unique subgroup $H'$ of $G$, we have
$$|\Hom(G_i, H)| = \sum_{H' \subseteq H} |\Surj(G_i, H')|.$$
So, if $|\Surj(G_1, H')| = |\Surj(G_2, H')|$ for all $|H'| < |H|$, and $|\Hom(G_1, H)| = |\Hom(G_2, H)|$, we deduce that $|\Surj(G_1, H)| = |\Surj(G_2, H)|$. $\square$

In particular, $|\Surj(G_1, G_1)| \geq 1$, so we deduce that there is a surjection $G_1 \to G_2$. Similarly, there is a surjection $G_2 \to G_1$. So, since $G_1$ and $G_2$ are finite, this means that we must have $G_1 \cong G_2$. $\square$

Comment: Maybe I'm getting at it throught the long route (a common complaint of my TAs when I was in Graduate School). I see the Lemma holds by refining Yoneda's Lemma, which means I would first prove Yoneda's Lemma and then do more work to get that the cardinality suffices...

Comment: Well, and it depends on whether Krull-Schmidt for finite groups in your toolbox or something you have to prove. Krull-Schmidt for finite length modules I have finally absorbed the proof of and now find elegant, but it is still hard; Krull-Schmidt for finite groups is, as far as I know, really hard.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Is the equation $|\text{Hom}(G_i,H)|=\sum_{H^{\prime}\leq H}|\text{Surj}(G_i,H^{\prime})|$ really true? It seems not to hold for $G_i$ being the cyclic group of order $2$ and $H$ being the permutation group on $3$ letters: the right hand side gives $4$ while the left hand side gives $7$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but I get 4 on both side? The subgroups of $S_3$ are $S_3$, $A_3$, three copies of $S_2$ and the trivial. The number of surjections from $G_i$ are $0$, $0$, $1$ (three times) and $1$, and $1+1+1+1=4$. @Larara

Comment: @DavidESpeyer I think I found out what confused me: $\text{Surj}(G,H)$ accounts only the surjections that are **also** homomorphisms? I was counting **ALL** (set-theoretic) surjections. Anyway, thanks for the reply!

Comment: Okay, edited to clarify.